# What is the equivalent of the htdocs folder in a JBoss AS instance

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, static-content, htdocs

Static files can be hosted in a Apache HTTP server under the htdocs folder, what would be its equivalent in a JBoss AS instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing to stop you putting stuff in `deploy\jboss-web.deployer\ROOT.war`, and it'll be served from the root, but you're strongly discouraged from doing so.  You should really package your content into a WAR and deploy that.

Remember, JBossAS is a JavaEE application server first, and a web server second.